# SQLiteException when querying a SELECT

Tags: java, android, sqlite, exception

I am developing an Android application with an SQLite database. It records transactions. The `transactions` table has the colums:

- `idTransaction INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT`
- `date DATE NOT NULL`
- `type INT NOT NULL`
- `details VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL`
- `notes VARCHAR(300) NOT NULL`
- `amount DOUBLE NOT NULL`
- `account INT NOT NULL`
- `category INT NOT NULL`

Also I made a method to get a cursor with all transactions:

```
// Select all Transactions
protected Cursor getTransactions() throws SQLException {
    Cursor mCursor = null;
    String[] colums = new String[]{"idTransaction", "date", "type", "details", "notes", "amount", "account", "category"};
    mCursor = this.getReadableDatabase().query("Transactions", colums, null, null, null, null, "name ASC");
    return mCursor;
}
```

In other class I made a method to move through the cursor that I get when I call `getTransactions()` method.

But the exception happen in this line:

```
mCursor = this.getReadableDatabase().query("Transactions", colums, null, null, null, null, "name ASC");
```

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: name(Sqlite code 1): , while compiling: SELECT idTransaction, date, type, details, notes, amount, account, category FROM Transactions ORDER BY name ASC,(OS error - 2:No such file or directory)

I checked the table name and all column names. I deleted and reinstalled the app but I do not know why the exception occurs.

Comment: You listed 8 columns, none of them called `name`, and you asked to sort ascending by `name` (that's what `"name ASC"` means), so why are you confused that it fails with "no such column: `name`"? Error message says it all.

Answer (score 2):

You're using an order by of `name ASC`, but you don't have a `name` column. That's what it means in the error message when it says `no such column: name`

Comment: If this really be the explanation, then you should probably just vote to close as a typo question.

Comment: I can't belived! But some times happen. :-P

Answer (score 1):

The Query method that you are using is of the form

```
query(String table, String[] columns, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String groupBy, String having, String orderBy)
```

as documented [Here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))

As you have mentioned **orderBy** as **"name ASC"**, but unfortunately your query string doesn't contain any such column, thus resulting in the exception what you have mentioned.

To solve this either add the **name** column also in your columns list else change the **orderBy** to any existing column name **eg- "date ASC"**.